# Procedure for obtaining Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas, uk-citizens, uk-residents

My wife and I are planning to visit Kos in Greece this summer. My wife is from Thailand and currently holds a Thai passport. We both reside in the UK. I am a UK citizen, my wife is here on a spouse visa and has a biometric residence permit.

What is the best route for us to go down to obtain a Schengen visa for her? Is it correct that we can get one for free as she is married to a UK citizen? Will ii have to travel to London to the Greek embassy to collect it when I live in Norwich city, or can it be posted?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: We expect users to search and try to answer their own questions before posting here; see the [Help pages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) for info on how this site works. As a UK citizen (you) and UK resident (your spouse) with Greece as your main destination, you'll apply through the Consular Section of the [Greek Embassy in the UK](https://www.mfa.gr/uk/en/the-embassy). On that emabassy page, you'll see that the Embassy has outsourced visa processing to the [Global Visa Centre](https://uk-gr.gvcworld.eu/en). Start by looking at the Global Visa Centre's page(s) to see what's required.

Comment: Since you are no longer an EU citizen, your spouse would not be eligible for a free visa to enter the Schengen Area togeather with (or when joining) their EU citizen spouse.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best route for us to go down to obtain a Schengen visa for her?

Follow the instructions on the [website of the Greek consular representation to the UK](https://www.mfa.gr/uk/en/visa.html?mission=lon), which will point you to [a third-party processor](https://uk-gr.gvcworld.eu/en) that seems to have offices in London, Manchester, and Edinburgh.  You can apply at the nearest one.

> Is it correct that we can get one for free as she is married to a UK citizen?

No, Brexit put an end to that a few years ago.

> Will ii have to travel to London to the Greek embassy to collect it when I live in Norwich city, or can it be posted?

If I understand the site correctly, they will return the passport by courier for an additional fee of £19.95.

Comment: FYI for OP: Submitting at VAC Manchester or Edinbrugh adds a min. of 5 days to the processing (for some reason)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella good catch.  I would guess that the reason is shipping time.  The actual decision is still made by a Greek government official, so they are probably sending the applications to the Greek embassy.  The London application center is around 11 km from the embassy.

Comment: It’s worth noting that while the passport may be returned by mail, the application must be made in person, as fingerprints need to be taken.

Comment: My wife has already had her fingerprints taken in April 2023 before arriving in the UK for her BRP,so they are already on the visa system.

Comment: @DarrenScott your wife will need to be fingerprinted. This has nothing to do with her residence in the UK or whatever biometric procedures she did for the UK permit. Two entirely unrelated things here.

Comment: Ok many thanks for your help,if i understand correctly she will only be able to use the visa for one trip.She has been telling me that her friends say its easier to apply in france for the visa and it lasts for 6 months allowing multiple journeys i told her i don't think this is correct.